# JavaScript prompt if/else response

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

When the object is clicked, the prompt shows up, but nothing happens when the answer is submitted. Is there an issue with the naming of the password? Any advice much appreciated!

```js
var password;
var pass1 = "thailand";
password = function password() {
  prompt('What was the first country we visited together?');
};
if (password == pass1) {
  //Change the page here
  console.log("Correct");
} else {
  console.log('sorry, try again!')
};
```

```html
<div class='one'>
  <p onclick="password()">Click me!</p>
```

Comment: Doing a password check in a JS file is a bad idea.

Comment: That's because your if statement is executed before your password function is invoked, and not invoked again

Comment: You need to do *everything* inside `functon password() { }`

Comment: _"you cannot set inline function like this"_ why not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I stand corrected, you can yes :)

Comment: @Esko - ok. I just wondered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store what's been inputted in the prompt. Also you made the comparison outside of the function before the prompt was displayed.

I updated the code, but you might need to make some adjustments :

```
<div class='one'><p onclick="password()">Click me!</p>

<script language="JavaScript">
var pass1="thailand";
function password() {
  var pass = prompt('What was the first country we visited together?');
  if (pass == pass1)
  {
    window.location="meesha.html";
  } else { 
    console.log('sorry, try again!')
  }
}
</script>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, this worked! except nothing pops up if you answer anything except for the correct answer, any ideas?

Comment: @SafiaKarasickSouthey It's expected, you do a console.log in case this is not he correct answer which is displayed in the browser console. You can (crudely) display an error message using alert('Sorry, try again').

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `function password()`. Removed that. 
And also added `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`

```html
 <div class='one'><p onclick="password()">Click me!</p>

<script language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="thailand";
password = prompt('What was the first country we visited together?');
  
if (password == pass1){ 
  window.location.href = 'meesha.html';
} else { 
  console.log('sorry, try again!')
};
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I suggest you try running it and then re-evaluate your statement.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Actually, the problem is that this won't work when the button is clicked. It will run during page load which is not what the OP is trying to do